# When developing for iOS, which devices do you typically test on?

Tags: iphone

I'm needing to purchase whatever devices are needed to do testing for iOS applications. My initial thoughts are to test on a first-generation iPod Touch and an iPhone 4. Testing on the old iPod Touch with 3.1 software will give a good indication on how the app will work with little memory, and the iPhone 4 will obviously be a test for the faster system.

What do you all typically test on before submitting an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At minimum, a device running the oldest OS that I list as my Deployment Target, the slowest device/OS combo that I have (e.g. a 3G running 4.0.x is likely slower than anything running a 3.x OS) and which the app supports, and the current/latest released OS.

A device which includes all the features that my app will support (e.g. mic, camera, gyro, GPS, etc., if needed.)

Optionally, an iPad if the app is Universal, or if not to see how bad 2X zoom looks.

Optionally, a device with a beta OS installed if it appears Apple is going to release it well before I plan on revising the app.

Comment: The problem with the firmware betas is that once you install them on a device, you can't do a rollback.

Comment: You can roll back firmware on iPod Touch devices.

Comment: Do you ever test on the original iPhone, or do you think that the 3G is good enough for testing purposes?

Comment: Audio hardware is different between the original iPhone and the 3G, so if your app does a lot of fancy audio stuff, testing on both may be appropriate.  Other than that, they have the same CPU architecture and clock rate, and offer very similar performance.

Answer (score 2):

So far all the apps I've submitted have been compatible with iOS 3.1.x, and I test them on my old 1st gen iPod Touch. I also test on my 3.2.2 iPad and my 4.0.2 iPhone 3GS.

My guess is all of these answers are going to be along the same lines -- test with as wide of a variety of devices as you can that are compatible with your app (i.e. meet the Minimum Deployment Version).

This is especially important if you develop Universal Apps that support 3.1.x. You'll find a ton of bugs with the hardware that you will never get with the simulator.

Comment: yea the bugs from a 3.1 universal are the biggest problem. can get weird things on the 4.0 version, or the ipad version, or the 3.1 version..not a good time.

Comment: Thank you for your help Shaggy Frog! Good to know about Universal apps.

Answer (score 1):

right now, I test using a 3g running 3.1 (a popular build), a 3gs running 4.0.2 (latest), a touch running 3.1.3(basically 3.1), and an iPhone 4 with 4.0.2.

Mainly try to keep a 3.x device around for sure, and then obviously a device with the most up to date OS.

Based on AdMob reports...around 98% of users are upgraded to atleast 3.0 and those that aren't shouldn't be your client base anyway (unlikely to use new apps).

Comment: Also, no applications targeting 2.x are being accepted for the App Store any more, so 3.0 is the earliest you can go.

Comment: I appreciate your help Jesse!

Comment: apps that support 2.2.1 that are still on the app store are fine however (not sure how itunes handles it though, they may make users update before even allowing access to the app store? )